# Why does the total from my query results not add up?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three queries that get stats from the database, but the total does not add up correctly for my results. If I do the math myself this is what I get:   `// 440728 / 1128 = 390.72`

However, the following is what is returned by my queries:

```
SELECT * FROM facebook_accts
         WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM  `user_accts` WHERE owner_id = '121') 
// returns 1128

SELECT sum(friend_count) FROM facebook_accts
                         WHERE user_id IN
                            (SELECT id FROM  `user_accts` WHERE owner_id = '121') 
// returns 440728

SELECT avg(friend_count) FROM facebook_accts
                         WHERE user_id IN
                            (SELECT id FROM  `user_accts` WHERE owner_id = '121') 
// returns 392.11 (number formatted to two decimal places by php)
```

Comment: can you post table structures for data types?

Comment: You have `SELECT * FROM facebook_accts`.  I feel certain you mean `SELECT COUNT(friend_count) FROM facebook_accts`

Comment: You have 4 records with no friend count at all (not even zero). So the average is computed as `440728/(1128-4)`.

Comment: friend_count is nullable and @Smandoli I count the number of returned rows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be happening because of column `friend_count` having some `NULL` values because `SUM` and `AVG` sunctions ignore `NULL` values. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659977/mysql-count-vs-mysql-select-which-one-is-faster).

Comment: is there a way to include these in the avg function?

Comment: `IFNULL(0,SUM(friend_count))` ... assuming your nulls SHOULD be taken as zero.

Comment: `AVG(ISNULL(friend_count),0)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the 1128 rows contain NULL values (which AVG and SUM ignore).