# Is mysql count(*) much less efficient than count(specific_field)?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [COUNT(*) vs. COUNT(1) vs. COUNT(pk): which is better?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better)
>   [count() and count(column_name), what's the diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876909/count-and-countcolumn-name-whats-the-diff)
>   [count(*) vs count(column-name) - which is more correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct)

The benefit of using `count(*)` in a select statement is that I can use it with any table and that makes automating scripts easier:

`count_sql = 'select count(*) ' +  getRestOfSQL('tablename');`

But, is it less efficient than using `count(specific_field)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Comment: What is `getRestOfSQL`? Can you give an example of a complete SQL query?

Comment: Not a duplicate IMO. Different databases do have different performance on different forms of `COUNT` with and without where-clauses and in different conditions of nullability and where indices are (I don't have any info for an answer, but I do know the answer is different in SqlServer and PostgreSQL which I do use). While the semantic difference of `count(*)`  vs `count(field_name)` is the most important thing, it's valid to wonder about this in the case of a specific db.

Comment: @JonHanna - The link I gave (also answered by @Mark) is tagged MySQL

Comment: @MartinSmith Right you are. I hadn't refreshed since following njk's links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For InnoDB**

If `specific_field` is not nullable, they are equivalent and have the same performance.

If `specific_field` is nullable, they don't do the same thing. `COUNT(specific_field)` counts the rows which have a not null value of `specific_field`. This requires looking at the value of `specific_field` for each row. `COUNT(*)` simply counts the number of rows and in this case can be faster as it does not require examining the value of `specific_field`.

**For MyISAM**

There is a special optimization for the following so that it does not even need to fetch all rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Isn't `count(*)` very slow for innoDB tables?

Comment: @MathieuImbert: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable` in InnoDB runs in O(n) time where `n` is the number of rows in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it wouldn't matter so much, as we're returning  the same number of rows.

This link covers it nicely

- [count(*) vs count(column-name) - which is more correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct)
- [Count(*) vs Count(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)

This link also explains more, [specifically with Oracle](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/BradSchacht/ssis/2195/select-count-vs-count-1-vs-count-columnname)